# How many Built-in Value types are there in C# (or even the CLR)

Tags: c#, .net, clr

We all know the 15 common value types that exists in C#:

```
sbyte, short, int, long, byte, ushort, uint, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, enum, struct
```

If you count `nullable` counterpart separately, it makes them 30.

I remember one of the MS certification books mentioning that "there are over 400 builtin *value* types in CLR", although I cannot find any references to it online, nor have I found anyone else mentioning it.

So I'm curious to know - is that all? If not, how do you find the rest and have you used them in any project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it means "in the .NET framework" rather than "in the CLR". (C# defines relatively few. Note that `enum` and `struct` themselves aren't types. The CLR itself knows of even fewer - it doesn't have any special support for `decimal` for example.)

Your list doesn't include things like `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, `Guid`, [`List<T>.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx) etc. Basically you could load a bunch of assemblies with reflection to find more. I suspect the certification guide really meant the set of value types in the framework.

Comment: Yeah, in the framework as a whole but not summing up the same types from different languages. `Guid` is a `struct`, which doesn't make it a separate type, right?

Comment: Wrong, it is a separate type. It's a struct, so it implicitly inherits from the type `ValueType`, but it is definitely a type in its own right.

Comment: @Mrchief: That's like saying that `String` is a `class`, so it doesn't count as a different type from `Button`. A type is either a struct, an enum, an interface, a delegate, a class, or a pointer type. That doesn't mean that all interfaces are the same type, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> "there are over 400 builtin value types in CLR"

Well any struct is a value type, so if this statement is accurate I assume it must mean including every struct in the BCL (not the CLR).

Answer (score 0):

`struct` is a value type, so count those as well.

Comment: Its hidden behind the scrollbar :)

Comment: `struct` isn't a type. What do you think `typeof(struct)` would return?

Comment: @Jon What I mean is that structs are value types, hence things like `Color`, `Point`, etc. count toward 400.

Comment: @Anton: Right, but that's very different :) All of the types listed are already structs...

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the 400 built in types includes structs and enums.

According to MSDN the actual types are only the ones you listed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx